# Using tf.control_dependencies with session.run

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I want to run a sub graph on some tensors in my CNN and compute their values. But before computing them I want tensorflow to pre-evaluate certain other tensors and update it in its internal computational graph. So it seems like an apt case to use `tf.control_dependencies`. Is the code below legit, I haven't seen a usage like this in sample code.

```
def run_graph( fetches, feed_dict):
    dep = [....]  # a list of tensors that I want to be pre evaluted before run
    with tf.control_dependencies(dep):
        res = tf.session.run( fetches, feed_dict)
```

Comment: Your  code is not  legit as `sess.run` is not a node/nodes and thus can not be controlled by `tf.control_dependencies`, if you want to update some value of variables in graph, you can use `tf.assign`.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted to know